# How to catch TransactionException in commit or rollback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions

I have method in a REST API service with a `@Transactional` annotation. This method should throw `MyException` even if the database is disconnected.

But when a transaction executes commit or rollback it throws a `TransactionException` if the database is disconnected.  How can I catch `TransactionException` in these cases to throw `MyException`?

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<RoomType> getRoomTypeList() throws MyException {
        return serviceImpl.getRoomTypeList();
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code parts?

Comment: I do not know why you need to return `MyException`, but I guess you could use a `@ExceptionHandler` to deal with `TransactionException`, `SQLRecoverableException` or any other. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers